# random.choices make it impossible to pick 2 times the same word

Tags: python

I'm a bit stuck with this problem.

```
import random

words = ["pomme", "poire", "banane", "citron", "peche", "abricot"]

print(random.choices(words, k=5))
```

I want to print a list where I can't get two times the same word.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use random.sample(words, 5) for random sampling without replacement.